# System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll raised Screenshot windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, screenshot, media

I am attempting to capture a screenshot and save it as jpeg into the `MediaLibrary` but received

> A first chance exception of type System.UnauthorizedAccessException
>   occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll at
>   lib.SavePicture(filePath, ms);

My code:

```
public static void SaveToMediaLibrary(FrameworkElement element, string title)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bmp.SaveJpeg(ms, (int)element.ActualWidth, (int)element.ActualHeight, 0, 100);
        var lib = new MediaLibrary();
        var filePath = string.Format(title + ".jpg");
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
        lib.SavePicture(filePath, ms);
    }
}
```

I am using Windows Phone 8 emulator for the test. What am I missing?

Comment: Reading the InnerException usually tells you the problem ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK I think I figured it out. I have to add an `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO` capability to your app's manifest!

Answer (score 1):

In the your application goto Manifest file and select capability tab then select all the checkbox. Then Save and run your apps. It should work